# How do method references in RxJava work?

Tags: java, lambda, rx-java, retrolambda

Can someone explain me, how come **both** of the lambdas can be replaced with method references here?

In RxJava, `map()` takes a parameter of type `Func1<T, R>`, whose comment states that it "Represents a function with **one** argument". Thus I completely understand why `valueOf(Object)` works here. But `trim()` takes **no arguments** at all.

So how does this work exactly?

```
Observable.just("")
    .map(s -> String.valueOf(s))  //lambdas
    .map(s -> s.trim())           //

    .map(String::valueOf)         //method references
    .map(String::trim)            //
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: The way method references work is that for instance methods like `trim`, `Type::instanceMethod` is equivalent to `(Type t) -> t.instanceMethod()`.  (More generally, `Type::instanceMethod` is `(Type t, extraArgs) -> t.instanceMethod(extraArgs)`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't play with RX in java, but please note, that `String::valueOf` is a static (aka unbound) function, while `String::trim` is a non-static (aka bound) function that have indirect `this` argument. So, in fact, both function takes single argument. In Java it's not that visible as it is in Python for example.

Comment: Note that you can actually explicitly declare the `this` argument in Java; it just isn't required.  `public void foo(Foo this) {}` is equivalent to `public void foo(){}`.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I like this. Wasn't aware. Since what java version? Do you know?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was added in Java 8.

Comment: The `Foo this` is called a "receiver parameter" and is specified in [JLS, §8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1). You can do the same thing with inner class constructors, e.g. an outer class `Foo` with inner class `Bar` whose constructor can be written as `Bar(Foo Foo.this)`.